# MySQL join two tables and add column values

Tags: mysql, join, sum

My knowledge of MySQL is not very in depth. If I have two tables that for example look like this:

```
Table1
Date        v1  v2  v3
05/01/2010  26  abc 45
05/02/2010  31  def 25
05/03/2010  50  ghi 46

Table2
Date        v1 v2  v3
05/01/2010  42 jkl 15
05/02/2010  28 mno 14
05/03/2010  12 pqr 64
```

How can I join them in a query by their date and have the sum of table1.v1 and table2.v1 and also have the sum of table1.v3 and table2.v3? V2 should be ignored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to do the following:

```
SELECT    t1.date, t1.v1 + t2.v1 AS v1_sum,
          t1.v3 + t2.v3 AS v3_sum
FROM      table1 t1
JOIN      table2 t2 ON (t1.date = t2.date);
```

And if you want the total aggregate of both columns, you can also do as follows:

```
SELECT    SUM(t1.v1 + t2.v1) AS v1_sum,
          SUM(t1.v3 + t2.v3) AS v3_sum
FROM      table1 t1
JOIN      table2 t2 ON (t1.date = t2.date);
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (`date` date, `v1` int, `v3` int);
CREATE TABLE table2 (`date` date, `v1` int, `v3` int);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('2010-05-01', 26, 45);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('2010-05-02', 31, 25);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('2010-05-03', 50, 46);

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES ('2010-05-01', 42, 15);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES ('2010-05-02', 28, 14);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES ('2010-05-03', 12, 64);
```

First query result:

```
+------------+--------+--------+
| date       | v1_sum | v3_sum |
+------------+--------+--------+
| 2010-05-01 |     68 |     60 |
| 2010-05-02 |     59 |     39 |
| 2010-05-03 |     62 |    110 |
+------------+--------+--------+
```

Second query result:

```
+--------+--------+
| v1_sum | v3_sum |
+--------+--------+
|    189 |    209 |
+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

create table corse
(
id  int(11),
cname   varchar(10),
cdet    varchar(10)
);

then create another table

create table stud
(
id  int(11),
sname   varchar(10),
ssub    varchar(10)
);

and then add primary key on table stud

**alter table stud add primary key(id);**

and then applied foreign key on corse

**alter table corse add foreign key(id) references stud(id);**

thats it last and final step

select s.id,s.sname,c.cname,c.cdet from stud s join corse c o
n s.id=c.id;